# Create a Label for each ComboBox in a Groupbox

Tags: c#, combobox

I am trying to create a label for each Combobox contained within each Groupbox on my form.  However, the following code works only if there is just one combobox inside the groupbox.  The same code works OK for Textboxes--a label will be created for each textbox.  It just doesn't work for comboboxes.  What am I doing wrong?

```
    foreach (GroupBox g in gbList)
        {
            foreach (ComboBox t in g.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>())
            {
                var borderColor = ChangeColorBrightness(EntryPoint.bgBack, Convert.ToSingle(-0.50));                    
                var n = t.Name;
                int x = t.Location.X;
                int y = t.Location.Y;
                int w = t.Size.Width;
                int h = t.Size.Height;
                Label label = new Label();
                label.BackColor = borderColor;
                label.ForeColor = SystemColors.WindowText;
                label.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
                label.Name = n + "Overlay";
                label.AutoSize = false;
                label.Width = w;
                label.Height = h;
                label.Location = new Point(x, y);
                g.Controls.Add(label);
                label.SendToBack();                    
            }
        }
```

Comment: It seems it goes to back of the combobox, Try : `int y = t.Location.Y-30;` and ;let me know the result.

Comment: Same thing, except the single label is shifted upward 30 px.

Comment: You means just one Label has been created agian ?

Comment: Yes just one label created for each groupbox.

Comment: I tested it and I found the problem, so I answered the solution. Try it and let me know the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "does not work" bit in english is likely "Collection was modified, enumeration operation may not execute." exception?

You cannot modify a collection you are foreach-ing on. Here you are adding a label to g.Controls while iterating on the same.

Comment: OK. So what would be the best approach?  First, create a list of Comboboxes?  If so, what type of list?  I've tried using an IEnumerable list of comboboxes but get the same result.

Comment: Solved.  You were right.  Created a combobox List from the IEnumeralble list.  Foreach-ing through the new Combobox list produced all the label boxes.

Comment: Why are you doing this instead of data binding?

Comment: No data are being used in these Labels.  They are being used only to create custom borders for other controls.  Not the best way, but I do not want to "start over" with a complete re-design of these common controls.

Comment: That's fine, but then if those controls are data bound, then you can modify their item templates and get rid of this code.